# what does "automatically move" mean for "remote branches"?

Tags: git

with
https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches
I found

> Remote branches are references to the state of branches on your remote repositories. They’re local branches that you can’t move; they’re moved automatically whenever you do any network communication. Remote branches act as bookmarks to remind you where the branches on your remote repositories were the last time you connected to them.
>   ...
>   To synchronize your work, you run a git fetch origin command. This command looks up which server origin is (in this case, it’s git.ourcompany.com), fetches any data from it that you don’t yet have, and updates your local database, moving your origin/master pointer to its new, more up-to-date position (see Figure 3-24).

what makes me confused is:
As

> they’re moved automatically whenever you do any network communication.

why do we need `git fetch` to manually synchronize?

Also, should we replace "remote branches" with "remote tracking branches" here?
Because "remote branches" usually refers to branches on remote machine.

Comment: Your Git only does network communication when you tell it to run `git fetch` or `git push` (or, technically, a few other cases like `git ls-remote`, but those other cases don't update any remote-tracking names). I hate the phrase "remote branches"—it's just wrong—and Git mostly uses "remote-tracking branches" now, but I prefer the phrase "remote-tracking names", since they're your names but not your branches.

Comment: @torek thus "do any network communicaiton" has nothing to do with the system network connection. "remote-tracking" is much better than "remote tracking" as the latter may implies the branch itself is remote. I hate all misuse of terminologies which makes simple logic hideous.

Answer (score 0):

> they’re moved automatically whenever you do any network communication.

It means that they are updated when you do a `git fetch` or `pull` (because pull contains a fetch) to represent the remote branche's state.

E.g. when I do a `git fetch` all remote branches will be updated to reflect the state of the remote repository's local branches.

```
   Remote Repository                     |     Local Repository
                                         |     
                                         |      refs/heads/master
   A -- B -- C                           |          |
             ^                           |          V
             |                           |     A -- B
           refs/heads/master             |          ^
                                         |          |
                                         |        refs/remotes/origin/master
```

if you now do a `git fetch` the local repository's remote will be updated.

```
   Remote Repository                     |     Local Repository
                                         |     
                                         |      refs/heads/master
   A -- B -- C                           |          |
             ^                           |          V
             |                           |     A -- B -- C
           refs/heads/master             |               ^
                                         |               |
                                         |        refs/remotes/origin/master
```

Thus you never update the remote branches manually. `they’re moved automatically whenever you do any network communication.`

Answer (score 0):

> they’re moved automatically whenever you do any network communication.

I guess it's talking about the **`HEAD pointer`** in Git which determines the current working revision (hence the files that will be placed in the project's working directory). Usually, when you would check out a branch (remote), **`Git will move the HEAD pointer automatically`** when you create a new commit, meaning **`you are automatically on the newest commit of the chosen branch`**.

Comment: so, "automatically move"  actually means "automatically move HEAD when manually run fetch/checkout"?

Comment: I guess yes, but if others have a different opinion I am open to hear more about it :)